# דע לפני מי אתה עומד on the ark

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, words, synagogue

In some *shuls* it says on the ark, *"Da Lifnei Mi Atah Omeid*." Is there any source from which that comes?

Comment: Where the words come from or where the custom to put them on the ark comes from?

Comment: דַּע לִפְנֵי מֵי אַתָּה עוֹמֵד
Please en english

Comment: @Avi Welcome to Mi Yodeya! That phrase means "Know before Whom you are standing"

Answer (score 4):

It's from Masheches [Brachos 28b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.28b.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), which brings a braisah stating that when Rabbi Eliezer became sick his talmidim asked him by what ways of life they could merit olam haba. He answered a few things, the last of which was the phrase "when you pray, know who you are standing before".

Rashi explains: דעו לפני מי וכו' - כדי שתתפללו ביראה ובכוונה. I.e. The reason to know before whom you stand is to induce awe and concentration.

Answer (score 2):

The words apparently appear in a number of places. [This](http://www.oztorah.com/2007/06/know-before-whom-you-stand-ask-the-rabbi/) site sources them, in the plural, to the talmud, Brachot 28b.